# How to rename/refactor a variable in Eclipse PDT in a Netbeans-like way

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, rename, eclipse-pdt

In the NetBeans IDE, changing a variable name in the parameters of a function also changes all occurrences of that name in the function. How can I get that behavior with Eclipse PDT? There is a **Refactor → Rename** item in the context menu, but it let me refactor only the file name.

This issue has been open since 2006 and you can vote for it in [the PDT bug tracker #149818](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149818).

Answer (score 4):

Code refactoring presence is the difference between PDT and Zend Studio as it is shown at [the comparison page](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/comparison#develop). So no, there is no way to do code refactoring in PDT.

Comment: But it may be supplied by some plugin. Zend Studio is paid product, developed by someone entirely different than PDT. So anyone can create a refactor plugin for PDT ;)

Comment: Should be possible to make a plugin

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy now, to do this in Eclipse for PHP Developers. My **eclipse** version is **Mars.2** Release (4.5.2) Build Id: 20160218-0600.

You just need to **put your cursor over the php variable** you want to rename, then **Right-Click** your mouse and select **Refactor -> Rename**. As soon as you do that, you will straight away see that all the variables, with the exact same name, within that php function, are now selected. You just need to **start editing** the variable. It will also give you visual cue, how all them are changed simultaneously, while you are editing.

The **php functions** within a class *(locally not globally)* can also be changed in similar fashion.

I find it easy, to use the keyboard shortcut on my mac, by pressing **`Command + Alt + R`**

Note: **Please don't highlight the variable name**, otherwise it behaves weirdly.